# How to edit css ::after element?

Tags: css, css-selectors, hover

So I have this website - https://community.entermedschool.com/courses/ and I'd like to change the CSS for an element. In the image below, I have circled the element which I'd like to change the CSS for.

[image]

So I've tried to access that element and edit its CSS but I don't see anything working. Here's what I've tried:

[image]

So I've found out that the item which I need to edit is the ::after thing. But I don't know how to. If I add my code within ::after, there's no difference.

So this is the code I added:

```
::after {
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

And now my page looks like this:
[image]

Any help in this would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is not valid selector, first specify your target element then use psedu-selector, like ```.my-class ::after{/*css rules*/}```

Comment: A quick read about pseudo elements (the ::after sort) will help and also look carefully at all the CSS which is associated with that after element, you have shown only part in the image. It's an after element on an anchor tag which you can select (plus the ::after).